# What's the right way to start session in symfony 1.4 if auto-start is disabled

Tags: database, session, plugins, symfony1, pdo

I'm trying to use sfPDOSessionStorage and it seems that it disables auto-start.
Question is when, where and how to start session it this case.
Also it issues

```
SELECT sess_data FROM sessions WHERE sess_id=?
```

and I do not understand why param is empty, and why this query is even there if auto-start is disabled and user is not logged in.

PS
Used http://grahamc.com/blog/how-to-setup-sfpdosessionstorage/ for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All database session storage classes disable session auto-start and none of standard session classes gives you control over cookie. One has to write own session handling class to implement custom storage logic or benefit form cookie-based caching on web-server side.